# Server error in localhost

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, xampp

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Error is like this:

> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a standard python cgi error message. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the application you are trying to run? Please check the application's logs and so on.